# Showing $A= A_r \bigoplus A_s$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups, direct-sum

I'm trying to answer the following question from Lang's Undergraduate Algebra:

[image]

I first attempted to prove this directly, however I failed at proving uniqueness. After my first attempted, I used an alternative, equivalent definition for the uniqueness of the sums $a= b+c$, i.e. $A_r \cap A_s = \{0\}$:

Assume $A_r \cap A_s \ne \{0\}$ then $\exists d \ne 0$ s.t. $d \in A_r \cap A_s \implies d \in A_r \: \text{and} \: d \in A_r$. We then have that $$dr = 0 \: \text{and} \: ds = 0 \implies dr + ds=0 \\ \implies dr = -(ds) \: \text{and} \: ds=-(ds)$$

Now, since inverses are unique we have $s=-r$, meaning at least one of $r,s$ is negative. This is a contradiction to our assumption that $r,s$ are positive. Thus $A_r \cap A_s = \{0\}$ and so uniqueness is satisfied.

That was the proof I came up with, but for some reason it just doesn't feel correct; I feel like I've assumed something in the "inverses are unique" step that isn't actually valid.

I was wondering if anyone can guide me as to where I have gone wrong, if I have gone wrong at all.

Comment: Indeed, the uniqueness of inverses does not imply directly that $s=-r$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can you perhaps clarify on why not? My logic is that if the inverse of $dr$ is $ds$, and the inverse of $dr$ is trivially $(-r)d = d(-r)$, why can't we not then deudce, by uniqueness of inverses, that $s=-r$?

Comment: The uniqueness of inverses says that for  example if $a,b,c\in G$ and $ab=ac$ then $b=c$. Here $s$ and $-r$ are not elements of $G$ so it simply doesn't apply (directly). All that follows from the equations above is that $(r+s)d=0$; this does not imply $r+s=0$ (for example in $\Bbb Z_2$ if $r+s=2$ then $(r+s)d=0$ for every $d$.)

Comment: I see. But could  not indirectly, and rather naively, show that $r=-s$ through an argument such as:

$dr +ds = 0 \implies \underbrace{(d+d+ \dots + d)}_{r \text{ times }} + \underbrace{((-d)+(-d)+ \dots + (-d))}_{s \text{ times }} = 0 \iff r=s$ or in this case $r=-s$

Comment: No. Given that $(d+d+\dots d)-(d+d+\dots d)=0$,, exactly _how_  does it follow that $r-s=0$? Saying that sum/difference equals zero says  just $(r-s)d=0$, and that doesn't imply $r-s=0$, regardless of how you rewrite it.

Comment: I believe I'm misinterpreting something here, but my line of thought was that if  $\underbrace{(d+d+ \dots + d)}_{r \text{ times }} + \underbrace{((-d)+(-d)+ \dots + (-d))}_{s \text{ times }} = 0$ then we can group the terms $(d+(-d))$ (since the group is abelian) and thus be left with a "residue" of $d$ or $(-d)$ terms, based on whether $r \ge s$ or $r \le s$. For instance, if $r= 5$ and $s=2$ we would be left with $d + d + d \ne 0$. Thus we would need that $r=s$. Sorry if my logic sounds really nonsensical, I'm just trying to make sure I don't have any misinterpretations.

Comment: But I believe I'm incorrect in assuming that $d + d + d = 0 \iff d=0$ (or in general that $md = 0 \iff d=0$). Sorry again.

Comment: Yes, you can group those terms like that. Yes, if $r=5$ and $s=2$ you're left with $d+d+d$. Or in other words, $(r-s)d$, exactly as I said. And yes, exactly as I've said two or three times, $md=0$ does not imply $d=0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n=rs$. Then for each element $a\in A$, $0=na = (rs)a= r(sa) = s(ra)$ and so $ra\in A_s$ and $sa\in A_r$. The sets $A_r,A_s$ are nonempty.

Suppose $a\in A_r\cap A_s$. By hypothesis, $ur+vs=1$ and so $a=(ur)a + (vs)a= u(ra)+v(sa) = 0$ as required.

Finally, $A = A_r + A_s$. For this, note that $A_r,A_s\subseteq A$ and so $A_r+A_s\subseteq A$. Conversely, write $ur+vs=1$. Then for each $a\in A$, $a=u(ra)+v(sa)$. Since $s(ra)=0$ and $r(sa)=0$, $(ur)a\in A_s$ and $(vs)a\in A_r$ as required.